# RecordRTC.js:37 Uncaught MediaStream is mandatory

Tags: javascript, recordrtc

**Problem** : Problem is that i am getting error as Stated in the title.

**Code** :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.WebRTC-Experiment.com/RecordRTC.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.webrtc-experiment.com/screenshot.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="elementToShare">
<div class="recording-controls">  <button type="button" id="startRecording" name="button">Start Recording</button>
<button type="button" id="stopRecording" name="button">Stop Recording</button></div>
<div id="myDiv" style="width:100%;height:100%"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var trace1 = {
z : [
[2, 2, 0, 0, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6],
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5],
[5, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 6],
[5, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 6, 5, 6, 6],
[3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5, 5, 5],
[0, 6, 6, 6, 1, 1, 6, 2, 2, 5],
[0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 5],
[0, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4],
],
cmax : 5,
cmin : 2,
colorscale: [["0", "#FF0000"], ["0.25", "#FFFFFF"],   ["0.555555555556", "#0000ff"],  ["0.777777777778", "#6CCE59"], ["1", "#FDE725"]],
// surfacecolor: [[0,"rgb(  0,  0,  0)"],[0.3,"rgb(230,  0,  0)"],[0.6,"rgb(255,210,  0)"],[1,"rgb(255,255,255)"]],
type : 'surface',
opacity : 1,
// autocolorscale : false,
name : "trace_name",
contours : {
  y : {
    show : true,
  }
},
};

var data = [trace1];
var layout = {
margin : {
    l: 10,
    r: 10,
    b: 20,
    t: 20
}
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
/* JAVASCRIPT CODE GOES HERE */
var elementToShare = document.getElementById('elementToShare');
var recorder = RecordRTC(elementToShare, {
type: 'canvas',
showMousePointer: true
});

document.getElementById('startRecording').onclick = function() {
recorder.startRecording();
};

document.getElementById('stopRecording').onclick = function() {
recorder.stopRecording(function(url) {
window.open(url);
});
};

</script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script> -->
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to record a video using RecordRTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using this:

```
<div class="elementToShare">
```

#### Please use this instead:

```
<div id="elementToShare" class="elementToShare">
```

Because your javascript was reading `id` not `class`:

```
var elementToShare = document.getElementById('elementToShare');
```

> PS. You can NOT pass `NULL` over RecordRTC constructor.

---

### Updated:

RecordRTC assumes that you are passing either `HTMLCanvasElement` or `CanvasRenderingContext2D`.

See how to read your DIV and get Canvas2D object:

- https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/blob/master/Canvas-Recording/webpage-recording.html#L138-L171

Comment: First of all. Sorry for the silly mistake in the question above,                     I am working on plotly js library and trying to use recordRTC to capture the webpage. I cannot use the pluggin which you have specified in your library. I need something as canvas rendering. I am not able to capture the plotly graphs in the video for some reason. The plotly graphs are generated in WebGL and i had discussed this with you yesterday after which you made changes to html2canvas version. Can you help or guide with capturing the plotly graph in the video? Does Recordrtc support webGl Capturing?

Comment: with the fiddle that you have made, i am not able to see the Scatter plot. Are there any changes i need to make in the browser? I am using chrome Version 51.0.2704.106 (64-bit)

Comment: You can copy HTML codes from this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9axrkm6n/2/ and paste on your own HTML file.

Comment: jsfiddle.net/9axrkm6n/2  shows completely dark screen in the recording.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67936072/recording-the-web-page-by-using-record-rtc-with-angular pls help on this. Thanks.