# RecordRTC audio+canvas recording does not run

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, recordrtc

I am trying to implement the RecordRTC javascript library, the audio+canvas recording one in particular, but for some reason the demo code does not run on my browser at all. I have tried chrome, IE, and Firefox.

The demo is: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/ffmpeg/audio-plus-canvas-recording.html

My console shows this message: 
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c79sG.jpg)

I tried using this previous help [RecordRTC.js:37 Uncaught MediaStream is mandatory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663627/recordrtc-js37-uncaught-mediastream-is-mandatory)

That fixed the console error I got, but the demo still didn't do anything.
Console always ends at audio/wav -> 246 KB.

Please help.Thanks.